# How do I retrieve old messages from a channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a bot that should allow me to read all the messages from a selected server and channel when I request it. I've tried using `channel.messages.cache.array()`, but that just returns `[]`. How do I effectively retrieve all (or most) of the messages from a Channel? Also, I'm using Discord.js v12.3.1.

```js
// logging in the bot
var data = {};
client.on('guildCreate', function (guild) {
    var channel = guild.systemChannel;
    var msgs = channel.messages.cache.array();
    console.log(msgs);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the reason that is not working is that when the bot joins the guild, none of the messages are cached. Instead, you should be using [`MessageManager#fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch). This method can directly request the Discord API and get message data from there!

```js
channel.messages.fetch().then((messages) => {
   console.log(messages.array());
   // ...
});
```

---

`MessageManager.fetch()` will by default only fetch the 50 latest messages, but you can override that with the `limit` option:

```js
channel.messages.fetch({ limit: xxx }).then((messages) => {
   console.log(messages.array());
   // ...
});
```